# Understanding the "distribution-valued" solution of a SPDE

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, intuition, stochastic-pde

Consider the Additive Stochastic Heat Equation (ASHE) given by
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u = \Delta u + \mathcal{\dot{W}}\\
u(x,0) = \xi
\end{cases}
$$
where $\mathcal{\dot{W}}$ is a white noise and $\xi$ is a $L^2$ r.v.
To me, it seems to be the case that people from the area already understand well this equation since before more modern techniques of the last few years (such as rough path theory).

One can proceed in a few natural ways to find a solution for such equation. For instance one could make use a Hilbert Basis $\{\phi_n\}_n$ for your $L^2$ space and solve a infinite system of independent stochastic ODE's and from there recover the original solution as the sum of those. The advantage of this method is that each of those ODE's are Ornstein–Uhlenbeck equations, in which you can get an explicit form for the solution.

So now there is the problem, it is well known that both of those methods only work in dimension $d=1$, for $d\ge2$, you get that the sum of the independent Ornstein–Uhlenbeck does not converge to a function in $L^2$, but instead as a distribution. So my main confusion:

Does a distribution-valued solution actually solve your problem?

I am sorry if the question seems superficial or too physically oriented,
I am just beginning in the area. I am just confused on how we are answering the original question. 
I am familiar with the notion of a weak solution for a PDE, so I understand not quite having the the full original desired properties, but being close. It is just that not even having a function anymore seems like a big step.

I am looking for a more intuitive way to see this, but I would appreciate any help or references.

Comment: That is just a fact of life like $2+2=4$. Distributions are more general than functions. So you can a priori try to find a solution of your SPDE in the space of distributions, even in the simpler $d=1$ case. It just happens that for $d=1$ the solution belongs to a smaller space of honest functions. Note that distributions are more physical than functions because nobody has a thermometer which measures temperature at a point $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$. The best one can do is some average of the temperatures around $x$.

Comment: Yeah, since I posted this, I got used to this fact and accepted it as the natural way to solve the problem. I suppose the question was a bit ill-posed, but I prefer to leave it here, maybe the discussion helps someone. But as a friend once told me "In mathematics, you don't really learn new concepts, you just get used to them."

Answer (score 6):

This will not answer your question about the ASHE, but another SPDE where we WANT a distribution valued solution. Hopefully this will offer some insight.

An important SPDE is [Kushner's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kushner_equation).

Kushner's equation arises in stochastic filtering theory. Stochastic filtering is when you have a noisy signal:

$$dX_t=f(X_t) dt+dW_t$$

and a noisy observation:

$$dY_t=h(X_t)dt+dV_t$$

Where $W,V$ are independent Brownian motions.

For example if you have a wireless signal that has some noise and your receiver has some noise, or something like that.

You want to find the best estimate for $h(X_t)$ given your observations. To do that, you want to find $\Bbb P(X_t\in A|\sigma(Y_s:0\le s \le t)):=\pi_t(A)$, a measure valued stochastic process called the optimal filter. $\pi_t$ satisfies Kushner's equation. $\pi_t$ is measure valued i.e. distribution valued. In this circumstance we WANT it to be distribution valued.

I am not sure about a physical interpretation of distribution valued heat distribution to be honest. However this is an example of a distribution valued solution to a SPDE with an important meaning.

Comment: Sorry, but what I mean is the distribution in sense of Schwartz, that is, like in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics). From what I understood, you are talking about a distribution in the sense of probability. So in the above, the ASHE equation gives not a random function $u_t$ or one of its conditional (probabilistic) distribution, the problem is that $u_t$ is not even a random function, but a random distribution (in the sense of Schwartz).

Comment: @kernel I know what you meant. Recall by Riesz that measures are (Schwartz!) distributions.